# Why use an acid when doing a scallops dish?

Tags: scallops

I'm trying to understand more about balancing a dish and I was wondering, why would you add some acidity to a seared scallops dish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shellfish is usually somewhat sweet in flavour. Acidity is the natural balance to sweetness.

Comment: Per this image https://pt.pinterest.com/pin/384424518172237883/ , shouldn't we also be able to balance the sweetness with spice and bitter?Why choose only acidity?

Comment: You can use other things per your liking. Citrus and certain vinegars are used a lot simply because they pair well with shellfish (and fish).

Comment: F....! pinterest and their mandatory signin, pls provide alternative source for image :)

Comment: Here it is : http://1m8t7f33dnra3sfk6v2rjurs.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/FlavorProfile_BlogSections_Draft3-01.png

Comment: Cindy, do you know if there is a book or list that tells you what pairs well with what?

Comment: @CarlaRaquel Yes, there is. It's called _The Flavour Thesaurus_. https://www.amazon.co.uk/Flavour-Thesaurus-Niki-Segnit/dp/0747599777/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1480423939&sr=8-1&keywords=flavour+thesaurus